# Access a facebook users photos and videos for the iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook

I was hoping someone can answer this question for me. I am trying to display wall posts, photos and videos for a certain user for example http://www.facebook.com/sony. I can see the wall posts,  photos and videos without signing up for Facebook. Do I need to use the facebook connect API to access the photos and and videos for sony so that I can display them in my iPhone application? I need to display the wall posts as a table view and the images and videos as a gallery very much like how the facebook app displays it. Any help or a API specific page would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Firdosh

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post to a facebook user's wall or status feed then you will need Facebook Connect API. [Here's a video on how to add facebook connect to your iPhone App](http://vimeo.com/3616452).

Here's the [API documentation page](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Connect_for_iPhone) you requested.

You will want to bear in mind, that Facebook video isn't able to be played on the iPhone as it's not encoded in any iPhone friendly format.

Comment: bad link to API documentation page!